# Is outgoing message encoding setting is available in office 365?

Tags: office365

As we have Outgoing message encoding setting in gmail, do we have such a setting in office 365?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can - description how can you do that: http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/outlook-help/change-message-encoding-used-to-send-messages-in-other-languages-HP005242882.aspx

Comment: Hii, Can you clarify if this link is still valid? When trying to open, it says "Sorry the page can't be found. Also settings for encoding the outgoing messages is not found in both gmail and O365.